# am trying to back when i press the back button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

am trying to back whenever i click the button but its not working, please can somebody help me out on what am doing wrongly

here is the code for the home page

```
import Header from './Header';
import TinderCards from './TinderCard';
import SwipeIcon from './SwipeIcon';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';


const Home = () => {

    const navigator = useNavigate();
    
    return (
        <div>
            <Header backButton={() => navigator.goBack()} />
            <TinderCards/>
            <SwipeIcon/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

here is the header component

```
<div className='header'>

            {backButton ? (
                <IconButton >
                <PersonIcon className='header__icon' fontSize='large'/> 
                </IconButton>
            ): (
                <IconButton onClick={backButton}>
                <ArrowBack className='header__icon' fontSize='large'/> 
                </IconButton>
            )}  
        </div>
```

here is the chats component

import Header from './Header'

```
const Chats = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Header/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

export default Chats

Comment: try `() => navigator(-1)`

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
{!backButton ? (
    <IconButton>
    <PersonIcon className='header__icon' fontSize='large'/> 
    </IconButton>
): (
    <IconButton onClick={backButton}>
    <ArrowBack className='header__icon' fontSize='large'/> 
    </IconButton>
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `navigate` function has two signatures:

Either pass a `To` value (same type as `<Link to>`) with an optional second `{ replace, state }` arg or

Pass the delta you want to go in the history stack. For example, `navigate(-1)` is equivalent to hitting the back button.

More info: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate

EDIT: Also, on Header component you need to invert your logic as you are adding the onClick only when there's no `backButton` prop, so if should be something like:

```
<div className='header'>
  <IconButton onClick={backButton ? backButton : null }>
    <ArrowBack className='header__icon' fontSize='large'/> 
  </IconButton>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i remove the backButton in the home component and call the navigate function in the header component

```
import { IconButton } from '@mui/material';
import { ArrowBack } from '@mui/icons-material'


const Header = ({backButton}) => {
    const navigate = useNavigate()

    return (
        <div className='header'>

            {backButton ? (
                <IconButton >
                <PersonIcon className='header__icon' fontSize='large'/> 
                </IconButton>
            ): (
                <IconButton onClick={() => navigate(-1)}>
                <ArrowBack className='header__icon' fontSize='large'/> 
                </IconButton>
            )}
    )
}

export default Header
```